# How to Preview Multiple Selected Image

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code for single Image preview, when we select a file from input field we can see the selected image in preview, but how can i do the same for multiple images preview.

here is my code for single image preview.

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#preview-image')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(150)
                .height(200);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="preview-image" class="img-prev rounded" src="#" alt="Upload" onerror=this.src="../assets/images/myfolder/no_image.png" />


<input type="file" name="featured_image" id="customFile" onchange="readURL(this);" required>
```

Jsfiddle : [My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JOHN_748/9mbcsjtv/1/)

Comment: jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/JOHN_748/9mbcsjtv/1/

Comment: Do the same thing in a loop?

Comment: Do not use the FileReader, use URL.createObjectURL instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Check all the things in this answer, and if not cleared, then modify as your need .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*multiple image preview first input*/

  $("#files").on("change", handleFileSelect);

  selDiv = $("#selectedFilesD");
  $("#myForm").on("submit", handleForm);

  $("body").on("click", ".selFile", removeFile);

  /*end image preview */

  /* Multiple image preview second input*/
  $("#mobile").on("change", handleFileSelect);

  selDivM = $("#selectFilesM");
  $("#myForm").on("submit", handleForm);

  $("body").on("click", ".selFile", removeFile);

  console.log($("#selectFilesM").length);
});
/*multiple image preview*/


var selDiv = "";
// var selDivM="";
var storedFiles = [];

function handleFileSelect(e) {

  var files = e.target.files;
  var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
  var device = $(e.target).data("device");
  filesArr.forEach(function(f) {

    if (!f.type.match("image.*")) {
      return;
    }
    storedFiles.push(f);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var html = "<div><img src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" data-file='" + f.name + "' class='selFile' title='Click to remove'>" + f.name + "<br clear=\"left\"/></div>";

      if (device == "mobile") {
        $("#selectedFilesM").append(html);
      } else {
        $("#selectedFilesD").append(html);
      }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  });

}

function handleForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData();

  for (var i = 0, len = storedFiles.length; i < len; i++) {
    data.append('files', storedFiles[i]);
  }

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'handler.cfm', true);

  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      console.log(e.currentTarget.responseText);
      alert(e.currentTarget.responseText + ' items uploaded.');
    }
  }

  xhr.send(data);
}

function removeFile(e) {
  var file = $(this).data("file");
  for (var i = 0; i < storedFiles.length; i++) {
    if (storedFiles[i].name === file) {
      storedFiles.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
  $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

```css
#selectedFilesD img,
#selectFilesM img {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#userActions input {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
#selectFiles img,
#selectedFilesM img {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="index.php" id="myForm" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  desktop:
  <input data-device="desktop" type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
  <div id="selectedFilesD"></div>
  <br/>
  mobile:
  <input data-device="mobile" type="file" id="mobile" name="mobile" multiple>
  <br/>

  <div id="selectedFilesM"></div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do not use the FileReader, use URL.createObjectURL instead